# Why do I have to kill ports after stopping ServiceStack?

Tags: windows, mono, servicestack

I have ServiceStack self hosted on Windows 2008 Server, on port 1300.  After stopping the project I have to kill processes (WebDev.WebServer40.exe) still holding 1320 and (System) 1300.  I also self-host ServiceStack on Centos on mono.  There I have to wait about 1 min. and then the ports clear.  Can anyone shed some light on what is holding the ports open?

Here is my Start() code:

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        ServiceStackHost app;
        app = new AppHost().Init();
        app.Start("http://*:1300/");
    }
```

Comment: I can't say I have ever come across this issue. On either Windows or Mono platform. Do it still occur if you shutdown the host using `app.Stop()`? And while I am sure the port number isn't the problems as you are using a number in the unreserved rage, what happens if you use say `9000` instead of `1300`? Which `AppHost` are you extending i.e. `AppHostHttpListenerBase`, `AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase` or `AppHostHttpListenerSmartPoolBase`?

Comment: AppHostHttpListenerBase is what AppHost derived from.  I am not using app.Stop() perhaps this is related to running in the debugger?  If you stop a debugger session I don't know it is going to cleanly exit. But it would be nice to figure out a way to exit clean, because killing port processes is a hassle.